# Export AD groups, usernames and full names to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

i'm trying to retrieve all groups, userID and names from AD and export this to CSV file with three columns, one for ParentGroupNames, then DisplayName, then memberName. The below works accept for DisplayName which seems to repeat one name for all groups.

```
function getGroups{

    $Groups += Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase    "ou=Groups,ou=DCM,ou=NTG,dc=prod,dc=main,dc=ntgov" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
    return $Groups
}

 $Groups = getGroups
  write-host "Groups:" $Groups.Count 

  $date = $(get-date).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
   $global:FileName = "Active Directory Group Membership - DCM -" + $date

   $results = @();

   foreach ($GroupName in $Groups){
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Sort-Object $_.SamAccountName |           


   ForEach-Object {
        $ItemProperties = @{
            "ParentGroupName" = (Get-ADGroup -Identity        $GroupName).SamAccountName;
            "MemberName" = $_.SamAccountName
        }

        if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'group') {
            $ItemProperties.Add("DisplayName","-");
        } elseif ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
            $ItemProperties.Add("DisplayName",(Get-ADUser -Identity  $MemberName -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName);
        }

        $MyItem = New-Object -TypeName psobject -property $ItemProperties;
        $Results += $MyItem;
        $ItemProperties = $null;
    }
} 
$results | export-csv -path "C:
```

Answer (score 0):

There an error in your code, change **$MemberName** to **$ItemProperties.MemberName** here's fixed code:

```
function getGroups{

    $Groups += Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase    "ou=Groups,ou=DCM,ou=NTG,dc=prod,dc=main,dc=ntgov" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
    return $Groups
}

 $Groups = getGroups
  write-host "Groups:" $Groups.Count 

  $date = $(get-date).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
   $global:FileName = "Active Directory Group Membership - DCM -" + $date

   $results = @();

   foreach ($GroupName in $Groups){
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Sort-Object $_.SamAccountName |           


   ForEach-Object {
        $ItemProperties = @{
            "ParentGroupName" = (Get-ADGroup -Identity        $GroupName).SamAccountName;
            "MemberName" = $_.SamAccountName
        }

        if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'group') {
            $ItemProperties.Add("DisplayName","-");
        } elseif ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
            $ItemProperties.Add("DisplayName",(Get-ADUser -Identity  $ItemProperties.MemberName -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName);
        }

        $MyItem = New-Object -TypeName psobject -property $ItemProperties;
        $Results += $MyItem;
        $ItemProperties = $null;
    }
} 
$results | export-csv -path "C:\1"
```